# Private class declaration

Tags: java, class, private

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Why can we define a top level class as private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913863/java-why-can-we-define-a-top-level-class-as-private)

Why can't we declare a **private** outer class? If we can have inner private class then why can't we have outer private class...?

Comment: And what would you do with that class?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth it would mean that at the next access level above class (the package), access could be modified.

Comment: @stevebot: That distinction is public/package, no?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes the distinction in the OP's question is that an inner class is at the class access level, whereas the top level class is at the package access level.

Comment: it's like making a party that nobody can attend, literally no body, even the owner, and the bartender

Answer (score 27):

Private outer class would be useless as nothing can access it.

See more details:

[Why can't we define a top level class as private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913863/java-why-can-we-define-a-top-level-class-as-private)

Comment: I would argue this  is not true. The access level above a class is a package, and it is meaningful to define access modifiers at the package level (see package-private).

Comment: I was wondering about a situation where you add a main method inside of the private class and access all of the other classes - public, protected, package-private - from within. This way no other classes will be able to instantiate this private class, which is probably what I want.

Answer (score 15):

`private` modifier will make your class inaccessible from outside, so there wouldn't be any advantage of this and I think that is why it is illegal and only `public`, `abstract` & `final` are permitted.

Note : Even you can not make it `protected`.

Answer (score 12):

To answer your question:

> If we can have inner private class then why can't we have outer
>   private class...?

You can, the distinction is that the inner class is at the "class" access level, whereas the "outer" class is at the "package" access level. From the [Oracle Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

> If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes — you will learn about them in a later lesson.)

Thus, package-private (declaring no modifier) is the effect you would expect from declaring an "outer" class private, the syntax is just different.

Comment: The question is why can't we declare the outer class like `private class MyClass`. As others have said, it's because it makes no sense. Of course we can declare it package-private like so: `class MyClass`, but I think the OP is clearly asking about `private class MyClass`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog it's not because it "makes no sense", it because Java's syntax for package-private requires no access modifier. You do not need to state `private class MyClass` because you can simply state `class Myclass`

Comment: But `private`, where it _can_ be used (like for class member declarations), does not mean package-private. It means no other classes can see the member. Class members can be defined as `public`, `protected`, default (no modifier), _or `private`_, and all of those have different meanings.

Comment: @GriffeyDog True, but the big misunderstanding is that class members vs. top level classes are entirely different access levels. `public` applied to a class member vs. `public` applied to a top level class have different meanings aswell.

Answer (score 4):

You can.

```
package test;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }
}

class B {
  // Essentially package-private - cannot be accessed anywhere else but inside the `test` package
}
```

Comment: I think that is wrong. class B has the default accessor, ence is available in the whole test package.

Comment: @ced - I see no visibility requirements in the question. Just a private outer class.

Comment: It might give misleading informations to future readers. "cannot be accessed anywhere else but inside `Test`". This statement isn't technically true

Comment: @ced Fixed That For You

Comment: I can't see a private class in here. There is only Public and Default class in here. Of course These works. Because Default class B is Accessible anywhere inside the package. I don't see how is this going to be an answer to above question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `private` class but you can have `second` class:

```
public class App14692708 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PC pc = new PC();
        System.out.println(pc);
    }
}

class PC {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I am PC instance " + super.toString();
    }
}
```

Also remember that `static` inner class is indistinguishable of separate class except it's name is `OuterClass.InnerClass`. So if you don't want to use "closures", use static inner class.

Answer (score 0):

private makes the class accessible only to the class in which it is declared. If we make entire class private no one from outside can access the class and makes it useless.

Inner class can be made private because the outer class can access inner class where as it is not the case with if you make outer class private.