# How I can compile a java file using a class in a separate file

Tags: java

and a little confused about the compile process:

There's my file structure

bin/
test/A.java
test/B.java

```
# B.java

package test; 
private class B{
    public static void say(){
        System.out.println("Hello.");
    };
}



# A.java

package test;
public class A{
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        test.B.say();
    }
}
```

then I compile A.java

javac -cp test/*.java test/A.java

It gives me error:

```
test/A.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class B
location: package test
        test.B.say();
            ^
1 error
```

Comment: Why B is a private class? try with public 
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/14692740/1026897]

Comment: Have you compiled Class B before Class A?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj No, I don't think I need to do that

Comment: @yozloy yep you are right, didn't need to.

Answer (score 2):

`B` should be a public class not a private class. Changing from `private class B` to `public class B` works out and compiles successfully.

Comment: But I think a private class can be accessed within the same package

Comment: no, it does not belong there. `private class B` as per JDK 1.6 is illegal

Comment: @yozloy if you want it to be accessible within the same package, use the default accessibility, which is leaving accessibility undeclared (i.e. simply `class B`).  That will be package-level.

Comment: @AdrianShum Thanks for pointing out this, you're correct, but after I take off the `private` it still doesn't work

Comment: @yozloy if you are declaring `class B` in `B.java` then it should be `public`.