# Control access in methods

Tags: java, inheritance, encapsulation, instanceof

I have a question about Java.

I have a class Say.java that has some methods, like `sayHello()`, `saySomething()`, `sayBye()`, ...

I have other classes too. I have a class `Person`, and two subclasses of `Person`: `Senior` and `Junior`.

My job to do is the following:

I have to set the Say.java class to be private, and create a public class SayFactory.java, with a method called getInstance. Then, to create a new instance of the Say.java class, I have to call my getInstance method with one argument: an instance of either Senior.java or Junior.java. If I create an instance of Say.java using a Senior.java object, I must be able to access all of the methods of Say.java. But if I do the same thing with Junior.java, I should be able to access all of Say.java's methods EXCEPT saySomething().

Can someone please explain how to do this and how it works?

Apologies by the way - I'm from Spain so my English isn't that great. If you don't understand the question, let me know and I'll try to write it out more clearly.

Comment: Create public getters/setters?

Comment: *"Someone know how to do this?"* - Yes.  Lots of people know.  And if you write the program, you will know too!  Hint: you will learn more about Java if you write this program yourself.  (You will learn more by just trying ...)

Comment: @StephenC Or at least if they attempt to write something, and then ask for help with the specific problems you face. At present, this is far too broad, as it seems to essentially be "Do my homework for me".

Comment: @Maik You seem to have fairly comprehensive instructions on what you need to do, but you haven't told us what problems you are having when trying to do it.  You need to attempt to write this program, then come back when you have *specific* problems and ask about them.

Answer (score 0):

First refer to this as answer to making a class private: [Java: Why can we define a top level class as private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913863/java-why-can-we-define-a-top-level-class-as-private)

For the objects that you want "private" you will have to make all the fields and possibly methods of it private (depending on what you need). Then as @user1071777 mentioned set up public getters and setters.

Some basic information on calling methods of an object:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html

To create the connection between classes you can have a class have another class as part of its definition and set it up through constructor or public setter.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I can't write `Private Class` but I can do a inner class.

I have a class `SayFactory` and within this I got another called `Say`

The `SayFactory` have a method called getInstance(), and in this method I create an object of `Say` class and return this object. The problem is, how to deny access to method `saySomething()` if the parameter of getInstance() is a object of `Junior`.